# The proper way to use your own class in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, class, themes

I have a class which generate an html, the php code is composed of 468 lines, I tried to put it in index.php of wordpress theme and it successfully render the html. The problem is, the html contained links (e.g., http://localhost/wp-explore/wp_commentmeta/list) which calls the method of the class, it cannot locate the class and method.

For example:

```
class MyClass
{

  function __construct(argument) {
    # code...
  }

  public function render_html() {
    /*code for rendering html*/
  }
  public function function_call () {
    /*code for executing function*/
  }
}
```

At the first visit of the website, `localhost/mysite` calling this method `render_html()` is successful, as it render html on browser, but the html contained link which call back `function_call ()`

What is the proper way to this in wordpress?

Comment: What error you got? Any screenshot?